# Adding Map of tunisia at the open street map with polygon

Tags: javascript, laravel, leaflet, openstreetmap

i need help i am trying to show the map of tunisia at the map there is nothing shown , this my code of javascript :
`

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var polygon = null;
        var draggable = true;

        initialize();

        function initialize() {
            // Create map for polygon drawing
            var map = L.map("map").setView([34, 9], 6);
            polygon = new MultiPolygon(map, $("#polygon-name").val());

            // Create tunisiaMap as background

            L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
                maxZoom: 19,
                attribution:
                    'Map data © <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            }).addTo(map);

            var totalLatLng =
                "(24.99539, 121.51033)|(25.02277, 121.53368)|(25.05295, 121.49935)|(25.01624, 121.44579)|(24.99508, 121.48252)";
            // Ajoutez ici les autres valeurs de totalLatLng

            var coords = new Array();
            // Add markers for polygon coordinates
            var splitLatLng = totalLatLng.split("|");
            for (var i = 0; i < splitLatLng.length; i++) {
                var latlng = splitLatLng[i]
                    .trim()
                    .substring(1, splitLatLng[i].length - 1)
                    .split(",");
                if (latlng.length > 1) {
                    coords.push(L.latLng(latlng[0], latlng[1]));
                }
            }

            polygon.addPolygon(coords, true);
            polygon.setCreatePolygonsCallback(updateDetails);
            polygon.setAllowDragging(draggable);
            polygon.setEditable(true);

            // Update coordinates displayed on 'C' press
            updateCoords();
            $(window).keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 67) {
                    updateCoords();
                }
            });

            $("#allow-dragging").click(function () {
                draggable = !draggable;
                polygon.setAllowDragging(draggable);
                if (draggable) {
                    $(this).html("Disable Dragging");
                } else {
                    $(this).html("Enable Dragging");
                }
            });

            $("#new-polygon").click(function () {
                polygon.createNewPolygon();
            });

            $("#clear-all").click(function () {
                polygon.deleteAllPolygons();
            });

            $("#update-polygon").click(function () {
                polygon.setName($("#polygon-name").val());
                polygon.panToPolygon();
            });
        }

        function updateDetails(p) {
            updateCoords();
        }

        function updateCoords(e) {
            var polys = polygon.getPolygons();
            var multi_coords = polygon.getPolygonCoordinates();
            $(".coords").empty();

            for (var j in multi_coords) {
                var name = $("<h3>" + polys[j].name + "</h3>").addClass(
                    polys[j].name,
                );
                if (polys[j].selfIntersects()) {
                    name.css("color", "red");
                }

                $(".coords").append(name);
                var coords = multi_coords[j];
                for (var i in coords) {
                    var c = $("<li>").html(
                        coords[i].lat + ", " + coords[i].lng,
                    );
                    $(".coords").append(c);
                }
                $(".coords").append("<hr/>");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

[image]

trying to show the map of tunisia , expect to show the map of tunisia and the polygon both , i have trying multiple solutions but no way , i am using leaflet

Comment: Cannot be reproduced - what is `MultiPolygon` supposed to be?

Answer (score -1):

hi i think you should add this code in your `initialize` function:

```
raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });
```

you didn`t define any source for your map.

Answer (score -1):

sorry, my last answer is for `open layer` library! for leaflet, just you should add this:

```
L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);
```

i think you can check your network to find more data about error! good look!

Comment: There's already a `L.tileLayer()` in OP's code.